# Ipad SDK. Keyboard dismis button not working

Tags: ipad, button, sdk, uikeyboard, dismiss

Having a problem with my app for iPad, that when i click the keyboard dismiss button, nothing happens.
I don't know if something is overwriting it or what it could possibly be.

[image: Ipad Dismis button]

When i click it really fast it presses once then you have to wait a second or two until you can click it again.

This problem is happening globally in all my views that show the keyboard.

Comment: Is your device Jailbroken? And is so, what tweaks do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

might not help you but in my case i had the same problem, only with uitextviews (which is odd)
and it turns out i was using ios[redacted] and was trying to use mainwindow.xibs for my main window like how we would in older xcodes.

some reason this doesnt work the same now(maybe after storyboards?) so you need to ditch your mainwindow.xib and do whatever setup was in there in code.
after doing that my uitextviews worked.

very strange.